# Automorphism group of $\mathbb{P}^{1}_{\mathbb{C}}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Show that every automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^{1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ is given by a linear automorphism of $\mathbb{C}^{2}$.

Equivalently: Show that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^{1}_{\mathbb{C}})=\operatorname{PGL}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$.

I have no idea where even to start, and I am feeling a little bit ashamed about that. I know this is not true for $\mathbb{P}^{n}_{\mathbb{C}}$ if $n\geq 2$. Can somebody please give me a hint?

Comment: Automorphism as what?

Comment: What do you mean? $Aut(\mathbb P^n) \cong PGL_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Comment: Is there a proof that does not rely on twisted sheaves?